# Using python variable within Jupyter LaTeX Markdown Cell

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I would like to fill in values in a report that I'm generating using a Jupyter notebook. While I am using the nbextension Python Markdown, this appears to only allow variables that can isolated, i.e. I can't fill in values that would be in a fraction.

This works, since it is only symbolic:

Markdown cell:

```
\begin{equation*}
\xi_b = \frac{\epsilon_c}{\epsilon_c + \epsilon_y}
\end{equation*}
```

But this code snippet wouldn't:

Code cell:

```
epsilon_c = 0.003
epsilon_y = 0.005
```

Markdown cell:

```
\begin{equation*}
\xi_b = \frac{{{epsilon_c}}}{{{epsilon_c}} + {{epsilon_y}}}
\end{equation*}
```

Is there some way to inject the python variable values directly into my LaTeX expression?

Comment: See this related thread that uses sympy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237257/force-sympy-to-print-math-in-mathjax-jupyter#_=_

Answer (score 5):

You can generate the `Latex` output from `Python` cell like this:

```py
from IPython.display import Latex

epsilon_c = 0.003
epsilon_y = 0.005
Latex(f"""\\begin{{equation*}}
\\xi_b = \\frac{{{epsilon_c}}}{{{epsilon_c}}} + {{{epsilon_y}}}
\\end{{equation*}}
""")
```

[image]